# Regex in R: get a list of keywords from text

Tags: r, regex

I want to use regex to get a list of keywords in a text. If the text says

`This is a random text Keywords a, b, c Hi stack overflow`
or
`Hi stackoverflow Keywords: a, b, Stack Overflow Some more text`

I would like to extract

`a, b, c`
and
`a, b, Stack Overflow`

I tried the following regex:

`.*?(?:Keywords:?\s)(.*?,.*?,.*?(?<!,)(?=\s[A-Z])){1,2}.*?$`

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/JKfFLl/9

But I'm not getting the "Overflow" part for the second string. The reason I put `{1,2}` in the code is to make sure it also captures keywords that consist of 2 words, but it's not working.

Comment: Will the keywords be only letter characters?

Comment: No, there might be numbers involved as well.

Comment: What determines if you want to capture one or two words for the last group?

Comment: It's basically just a heuristic, because right now it just stops at 'Stack'. To put it differently, what I want is to extract this comma separated list of terms (which might be multiple words). However, these terms might be separated by a comma, semicolon, dot, slash, ...

Comment: Currently I don't understand how you delimit between the last key word and the following text. If the third keyword is 2 words, does it have a specific pattern? does the following text have certain characteristics?

Comment: Basically the text always consists of a text, followed by a list of keywords and followed my a subtitle and more text. At first I thought it was easy because you could just get the text after the "Keywords" title up until the point a capital letter (from the subtitle) was found. However, turns out the keywords themselves can also contain capital letters...

Comment: If you can find a surefire way to differentiate between keyword end and subtitle beginning please add that to your post an I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments on the OP and this answer; This regex captures an arbitrary number of `,./;` delimited keywords which may have 1 or 2 words

https://regex101.com/r/IHPCuN/5

```
^.*?(?:Keywords(?::|-|--)?)\K((?:(?:\s\w+){1,2}[,.;|])+(?:\s\w+){1,2}).*$
```

This captures 1 or 2 words at the end of the list, but without any differentiation between the end of the list and the rest of the text this will always capture 2 words at the end.

Note: the `\K` is not specifically necessary, but will increase performance.

Comment: See this example: https://regex101.com/r/IHPCuN/2 Why is it not capturing 'Capture This'?

Comment: Because of the maximum 2 repetitions of the `(?:.+?\s)` created by the `{1,2}`. If you change it to `{1,4}` it will capture 'Capture This' https://regex101.com/r/IHPCuN/3

Comment: I think we're talking about something else? Check https://regex101.com/r/IHPCuN/4, I want to extract all the keywords.

Comment: So you want to grab an arbitrary number of `,./;` delimited keywords which may have 1 or 2 words?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do